# What are the alternatives of PHP-ffmpeg and LaravelFFMpeg repo

Tags: php, video-editing

I use Laravel and PHP. I'd convert video during streaming, and I'd like to put watermark to the video. I spent days to try to set up the pascalbaljetmedia/laravel-ffmpeg repo from GitHub and try to use PHP-ffmpeg but I couldn't.

Are there any alternative for the same usage? I use

- Laravel 5.8
- PHP 7.1
- Windows 10
- WAMP server